# How to get Rails 3.2.22.5 String#to_json behaviour back in Rails 4.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, escaping

I'm upgrading a Rails 3.2.22.5 app to 4.2.8 (while staying on Ruby 2.3.1p112).

After the upgrade this:

```
mssngr(dev)> puts "".to_json
"\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e\uf60e"
```

changes to this:

```
mssngr(dev)> puts "".to_json
""
```

While the unescaped version is probably the "right" version, I have code that expects the escaped version. Is there a way to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: I don't have an mb4 console, but could you try to_json_without_active_support_encoder?

Comment: Same, unfortunately.